# How to fix a redirect from naked domain that times out when https is put in front but works with http

Tags: redirects, https

I am a developer and have very little knowledge of DNS and hosting, etc.  A client for an app I have inherited recently switched over to running everything over https only.  However when this URL `https://website.io` is used it just spins and times out and will not redirect to `https://www.website.io` and I do not really understand why.  The URL `http://website.io` works and redirects to `https://www.website.io` as expected.

I did read the posts on this site I could find that seemed related but did not find anything to solve.

The site is a ROR application hosted on AWS and uses a multi-domain SSL certificate to provide SSL to their sites. For that instance on AWS there are two load balancers, one of them handles the https (443) and has the certificate on it. The naked domain `website.io` is on the multi domain SSL certificate so I assumed that would solve the issue. The SSL certificate is in place and all that works fine, it is just the case of this one redirect that I do not understand, can anyone help?

Comment: It is not the redirect that is the problem. It is the fact that your HTTPS site is not working. There is not enough actionable information here for us to help you. You are probably better off calling technical support and starting there. Cheers!!

Comment: So this would need to be solved in the DNS dashboard, like Network Solutions dashboard or whatever, by the person who actually owns the domain?  I do not have access to that I just develop the site but they are asking why this redirect hangs up.  For me there is no tech support to call.

Comment: You mentioned that you cannot access the site using HTTPS. Redirecting to HTTPS will only fail. Until you fix the HTTPS problem, redirecting to it will not work. It is not the redirect that is the problem. It is the fact that your site cannot be accessed using HTTPS that is the problem. This is not likely to be a DNS problem since both requests are referring to the same URL using different protocols. The web server is not responding to requests on port 443. This is the problem that needs to be addressed.

Comment: Sorry, I think I might not have asked the question correctly, with `www.*** ` it it does run https, and when visiting `http://website.io` it will redirect to `https://www.website.io`.  But when visiting `https://website.io` it hangs.  The site it self does run `https`.

Comment: It is one of two problems. One could be the code is wrong. Less likely, but possible. The other is that there is no certificate on website.io and it hangs there. Very likely. Without a certificate on website.io, the users browser will not see the redirect. It is quite possible that whoever set this up did not install a certificate on website.io. This is a common mistake.

Comment: Anytime! That is why we are here. See what you can do to check things out. Cheers!!

Comment: I concur, @closetnoc should add that as an answer - that is as much as can be deduced at this end. It looks like the server is simply not responding to requests to `https://website.io` (ie. `website.io` on port 443), probably because there is no SSL cert / VirtualHost for the domain apex. (If the code was wrong, I would still expect to see a redirect - check the network traffic. It's not a DNS problem because `http://website.io` works.)

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, wouldn't having `website.io` on the SSL certificate solve the issue?

Comment: You certainly need to add that domain onto a certificate.   You also need to configure the server.  You'll need to make sure you have a `*:443` virtual host that can handle that name and code in place to issue a redirect to the main site.

Comment: @RockwellRice Were you able to solve this problem?  I too see the same problem. In my case, the site is hosted by blogger. It has HTTPS, and redirects from HTTP to HTTPS. Only when using the naked domain it times out:    `https://my-naked-domain.com`

Comment: @ozkary To be honest I cannot totally remember but I feel it had to do with something in the nginx file ultimately.  But I do not manage this site any longer so I cannot be totally sure, best of luck with it!

Answer (score 1):

See if your apache http server config has a line like

- 'ServerAlias  website.io'

or

- 'ServerAlias  *.website.io'